Problemas de react-native-maps en Huawei
Estoy probando implementar mapas en una app que estoy desarrollando en React Native con Expo y al probar la app en desarrollo en dispositivos Huawei, tengo el errror de que no se pueden inicializar los servicios de Google
Quisiera saber si existe una manera de solucionar este error o si existe alguna otra herramienta de mapas similar y que sea compatible para Huawei

1. Utilizar HMS (Huawei Mobile Services) y Map Kit
Huawei ofrece su propio servicio de mapas llamado Huawei Map Kit, que puede reemplazar Google Maps en dispositivos Huawei. Aquí te dejo los pasos para integrarlo:

Configurar Huawei Mobile Services (HMS):
Debes integrar los HMS en tu aplicación siguiendo los pasos de Huawei para configurar la AppGallery y el Huawei Developer Console. Debes registrar tu app y obtener las credenciales necesarias.

Agregar Huawei Map Kit:
Instala las dependencias necesarias para Huawei Map Kit. Puedes seguir la documentación oficial de HMS Map Kit.


Ejemplo de integración:
npm install @hmscore/react-native-hms-map

Luego configura y usa los mapas de Huawei en tu app. Puedes consultar la documentación de HMS Map Kit para React Native en este enlace.
2. Detectar Huawei y mostrar Map Kit condicionalmente
Si tu app debe ser compatible con dispositivos tanto Huawei como no Huawei, puedes implementar una detección de dispositivo. Dependiendo del dispositivo, decides si mostrar Google Maps o Huawei Map Kit.
Ejemplo de cómo detectar dispositivos Huawei:
import { Platform, NativeModules } from 'react-native';

const isHuawei = () => {
  const brand = NativeModules.DeviceInfo.getBrand();
  return brand.toLowerCase() === 'huawei';
}

if (isHuawei()) {
  // Cargar Huawei Map Kit
} else {
  // Cargar Google Maps
}

3. Usar Mapas de Open Source como Mapbox
Mapbox es una alternativa popular a Google Maps y es compatible con dispositivos que no tienen acceso a Google Mobile Services, como los de Huawei.

Instalar Mapbox:
Puedes instalar react-native-mapbox-gl para implementar Mapbox en tu app.
npm install @react-native-mapbox-gl/maps


Configura Mapbox en tu proyecto y obtén una clave de API en la página oficial de Mapbox.

Utiliza la documentación de react-native-mapbox-gl para implementarlo en tu app.


Eso seria lo mas simple por donde podrias empezar
